# get jquery chained selector variables back to php form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

So, I'm pretty much a novice when it comes to programming and I would certainly appreciate a bit of help with an issue I'm having trouble getting my head around. Simply put, how do I get the selected variables from jquery.chained.remote.js back into my form for processing?

Here's the functioning, sort of, sample page.

http://www.noradaron.com/samplesearch/index.php

The dropdown list functions just fine but I just don't understand how to get the selected values back into my form. Yes, I will freely admit my knowledge is limited and I may not fully understand the answer once it is given. Regardless, I certainly appreciate any help I can get. Please let me know if there is anything else I could provide that would make my question more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Attach submit event handler to your form like this:

```
$('form[name="search-vehicles"').submit(function() {
//code
});
```

Inside code grab the values like:

```
var value = $('#vType').val();
```

And update your text with the new values. However I recomment you to not write **"text
more text"** But to write your text inside **DIV**s or **SPAN**s with **ID**s so you can easily access them and change their values like:

```
<div id="selectedName"></div>
```

Then you can use:

```
$('#selectedName').html(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside putting id="vType" add name="vType" (and so on) so you can have your data sent back to server with either GET or POST .

Comment: geez, thank you so much I feel like a total idiot. I was trying to use GET the whole time anyway. I guess sometimes it's the most simple thing that one overlooks! I truly thank you and I hope you have a wonderful day.